# pyspark inner join and intersect on two dataframes from same source is broken

Tags: inner-join, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am using spark-2.0.0. When I am trying to intersect two dataframes from same source the answer is not as expected. Its the same with inner join.

```
df = sqlContext.read.parquet("path to hdfs file").select('col1','col2')
w1 = df.filter(df.col1 == 1)
w2 = df.filter(df.col2 == 2)
w1.select('col1').intersect(w2.select('col1')).show()
#Answer is just w1
w2.select('col1').intersect(w1.select('col1')).show()
#Answer is just w2
w1.intersect(w2).show()
#This should give empty data frame but output is w1
w1.join(w2,w1.col1==w2.col2)
#this is giving out put as if w1.join(w1,'col1)
```

This behavior is happening only when i am reading through hdfs. If i construct a dataframe in program it self it is behaving as expected.

I tried using alias as well, as given in this link to temporarily fix the problem still not working.
http://search-hadoop.com/m/q3RTtOaknEYeLLi&subj=Re+Join+on+DataFrames+from+the+same+source+Pyspark+